# Inserting a table view row data from another table view?

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, xcode11

So I have two table views. `MainTableView` and `SecondaryTableView`, The `MainTableView` has empty rows with no text. A Table view cell is configured though. These rows have the option to delete. The `SecondaryTableView` rows also have an editing style in which I am using to ADD the selected row into the `MainTableView` rows.

```
class MainVC: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet var mycartableview: UITableView!
var passedcar = String()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    mycartableview.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
    
}

var diynames: [String] = ["a","b","c"]

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    
    return diynames.count
    
     }
   
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) ->   UITableViewCell {
    let diyname = diynames[indexPath.row]
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "mycarcell") as! mycarcell
    cell.mycartitle.text = diyname
  
    return cell
   }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete{
        diynames.remove(at: indexPath.row)
          tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        tableView.endUpdates()
          }
   
}
```

`SecondaryVC` code:

```
class MainVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

let names = ["aa","ba","ca","da","ea",]
 
@IBOutlet var tableview: UITableView!
@IBOutlet var slctedcar: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
  
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    self.tableview.backgroundColor = .white
   

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

   
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return  names.count
   
    return  names.count
   }
   
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "diylistcell") as! diylistcellTableViewCell
  cell.diytitle.text = names[indexPath.row]
    
    return cell
     }


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
     return true
 }
 
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
      let addbutton = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Add") { (rowAction, indexpath
        ) in
        print("Add clicked")


        
      let mycarvc = MyCarViewController()
        mycarvc.diynames.append(contentsOf: self.hcdiynames)
        
        let hcindexpath = IndexPath(row: mycarvc.diynames.count - 1, section: 0)
        mycarvc.mycartableview.insertRows(at: [hcindexpath], with: .automatic) //this is where the error occurs. Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value
        mycarvc.mycartableview.endUpdates()

        
        
}
      addbutton.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
    
    return [addbutton]
}
```

[Clear Image of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALsFM.png)

That's where my pain is coming from. As you could see in the picture above the highlighted area it says that my array coming from the main vc is a count of 8. That checks out completely because the original array has 3 and I am appending 5 new ones. The error implicitly found nil has left me clueless in this scenario. If anybody has any suggestions on how to fix this problem it would be highly appreciated, thank you .

Answer (score 0):

This is a common error when you try to transfer data between VC , I usually create 1 variable which will store what I want and after in the viewDidLoad() I give the value of this variable to what I really want , IN your code the equivalent is

```
class MainVC: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet var mycartableview: UITableView!
var passedcar = String()
// I JUST CREATED THE VARIABLE WHICH WILL HOLD OUR VALUES
var diynamesContainer = [String]()
///////////////////
var diynames: [String] = ["a","b","c"]
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    mycartableview.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
    // I ADD TO OUR ARRAY THE VALUE OF THE diynamesContainer
     diynames.append(contentsOf: diynamesContainer)
    //////////////////
     

    
}



  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    
    return diynames.count
    
     }
   
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) ->   UITableViewCell {
    let diyname = diynames[indexPath.row]
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "mycarcell") as! mycarcell
    cell.mycartitle.text = diyname
  
    return cell
   }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete{
        diynames.remove(at: indexPath.row)
          tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        tableView.endUpdates()
          }
   
}



/*
// MARK: - Navigation
```

and in our main vc you replace

```
let mycarvc = MyCarViewController()
 mycarvc.diynames.append(contentsOf: self.hcdiynames)
```

by

```
    let mycarvc = MyCarViewController()
    mycarvc.diynamesContainer = self.hcdiynames
```

Try to run your code, the error will go away

Comment: still giving me the same error, unexpectedly found nil. Is there any way to unwrap the data passed ? would that eliminate this ? thanks for the suggestion anyway.

Comment: you can try to unwrap in the viewDidLoad() ,                                                                `guard let diynamesContainer = diynamesContainer else {return}`